# Flex tree : any way to reduce vertical spacing between nodes?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flash-builder, flex4.6

I would like the tree to render each node with less vertical space between them.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `mx:tree` (and in lists as well), you can reduce the `rowHeight`property, which is the height of the rows in pixels.